# For Loop to Move and Rename .html Files - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm asking for help in trying to create a loop to make this script go through all files in a local directory. Currently I have this script working with a single HTML file, but would like it so it picks the first file in the directory and just loops until it gets to the last file in the directory.

Another way to help would be adding a line to the string would add a (1), (2), (3), etc. at the end if the names are duplicate.

Can anyone help with renaming thousands of files with a string that is parsed with BeautifulSoup4. Each file contains a name and reference number at the same position/line. Could be same name and reference number, or could be different reference number with same name.

```
import bs4, shutil, os

src_dir = os.getcwd()
print(src_dir)

dest_dir = os.mkdir('subfolder')
os.listdir()

dest_dir = src_dir+"/subfolder"
src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, 'example_filename_here.html')
shutil.copy(src_file, dest_dir)

exampleFile = open('example_filename_here.html')
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.read(), 'html.parser')

elems = exampleSoup.select('.bodycopy')

type(elems)

elems[2].getText()

dst_file = os.path.join(dest_dir, 'example_filename_here.html')
new_dst_file_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, elems[2].getText()+ '.html')

os.rename(dst_file, new_dst_file_name)
os.chdir(dest_dir)

print(elems[2].getText())
```